# Need something similar to ProC to achieve Embedded CQL

Tags: cassandra, cql, datastax

We are migrating our application from SQL to CQL. We use Embedded C++ to execute the queries. Can any one suggest something similar to Pro C for CQL

Comment: Unfortunately we don't use Java in our application. Can any one suggest any link which explains how to use Datastax-C++ driver and examples of how we can code cql queries in C++

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to run embedded C or C++ code in Cassandra today.

#### A couple of alternatives:

1) Potentially, you can use [Cassandra Triggers](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/whats-new-in-cassandra-2-0-prototype-triggers-support) which allow you to run embedded java code.

**Note** that the triggers implementation requires you to distribute your Jar across the cluster and it requires a thorough knowledge of Cassandra internals.

2) You may be better off using something like spark batch jobs or spark streaming to add your logic. This is less risky than 1) and does not require as much knowledge of Cassandra internals.

Check out Sameer's [webinar](http://www.oreilly.com/pub/e/3234) to learn more about Spark and Cassandra.

3) Move your logic to the app layer.

#### Relevant Jiras for futures:

1) [User Defined Functions](http://planetcassandra.org/blog/user-defined-functions-in-cassandra-3-0/) (ETA 3.0) are probably the end solution to what you're looking for. You'll be able to run embedded code in any language.

2) [Change data capture](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-8844) (ETA 3.1) - will give users the capability to take action based on changes on C* tables.

Comment: I see there is a datastax C++ driver supporting connectivity from C++ to Cassandra CQL which is available in Datastax website. Can that be used ? Do anyone have experience doing so, please let us know

Comment: This is unrelated and probably belongs in another question but yes, this driver is GA and is being used relatively widely. Check out the mailing list https://groups.google.com/a/lists.datastax.com/forum/#!forum/cpp-driver-user

Comment: Note: the C++ driver allows your C/C++ app to write to cassandra, it does not execute embedded C++ inside of Cassandra. Do you see the distinction? Did I misinterpret your original question?

Comment: I see the distinction. Thanks Phact for the mailing list link